# Omniauth.params are empty hash (api_only)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

### Environment

- Ruby **2.7.4 (Rails API only)**
- Rails **6.0.4.1**
- Devise **4.8.0**
- Omniauth**1.8.1**

### Current behavior

Getting omniauth missing_credentials? error. The request.params is always an empty hash even though I provide username and password in the request body via POST method. I can see the body params when debugging actual controller, but it looks like those params are not passed to omniauth request.

[image]

[image: screen1]

[image: screen2]

**Controller**:

```
module Api
  module V1
    module Auth
      class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController #< ApplicationController#
        include ActionController::Cookies
     
        def ldap
          puts request.env['omniauth.auth'] # => NULL

        end

        def failure
          puts "request.env['omniauth.auth']: #{request.env['omniauth.auth']}" # => NULL
          puts "request.env['omniauth.params']: #{request.env['omniauth.params']}" # => {}
          puts "params: #{params}" # => { "username": "myusername", "password": "mypassword" }

          render json: { status: "fail" }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Application.rb**:

```
    config.api_only = true
    config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_interslice_session'
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
    config.middleware.use config.session_store, config.session_options
```

**Routes.rb**:
`devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'api/v1/auth/omniauth_callbacks' }`

**Devise.rb**:

```
config.omniauth :ldap, :host => 'XXX.com',
                :port => 389,
                :method => :plain,
                :base => 'cn=accounts,dc=int,dc=dostack,dc=io',
                :uid => 'uid',
                :try_sasl => false,
                :bind_dn => "uid=XXX,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=int,dc=dostack,dc=io",
                :password => "xxxxxxxx"
```

**Response**:
[image]

### Expected behavior

Authenticate using omniauth (LDAP or using any other omniauth provider)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `params['username']` and `params['password']` instead?

Comment: request['username'] and request['password'] are defined in the gem, so assuming this is correct.

Comment: Could you also show how are you making the actual request? I have a hunch that maybe `Content-Type` header is not set there.